# Average of one table based on another

Tags: powerbi, average, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables, `OrgStructure` which is a very basic for of an organizational structure, and `Tickets` which is a list of tickets submitted by employees in the said organization. The two tables are linked by `Manager` field.

### OrgStructure:

```
Manager,Employee
Chelsea,Anna
Chelsea,John
Chelsea,Mike
Chelsea,Nicole
Chelsea,Phil
Nicole,Arthur
Nicole,Brandon
Tom,Brian
Tom,Katie
Tom,William
```

### Tickets:

```
TicketNo,Manager,Employee
T1,Chelsea,John
T2,Chelsea,John
T3,Chelsea,Nicole
T4,Chelsea,Phil
T5,Nicole,Brandon
T6,Tom,Katie
T7,Tom,Katie
T8,Tom,William
```

My goal is to calculate the average of tickets submitted per manager.

For example, Chelsea has 5 employees under her, and in the `Tickets` table, there are 4 tickets where she's listed as the manager. What I want is `4/5` which is the average amount of tickets submitted by the people she manages. Obviously the numerator and denominator are in two different tables. So how do I calculate the said value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems as simple as

```
AvgTicketePerManager = 
DIVIDE ( COUNT ( Tickets[TicketNo] ), COUNT ( OrgStructure[Employee] ) )
```

[image: Matrix Visual]